# TreeInstance position to world position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to get the position of trees (TreeInstance) on the terrain.
I have the following code that I use but the position of the tree is not correct.

```
foreach (var treeInstance in terrainData.treeInstances) 
{
    resourcePositions.Add(treeInstance.position);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TreeInstance position is actually related to the height map of the terrain.
To convert it to the world position you should do the following:

```
foreach (var treeInstance in terrainData.treeInstances) 
{
    var treeInstancePos = treeInstance.position;
    var localPos = new Vector3(treeInstancePos.x * terrainData.size.x, treeInstancePos.y * terrainData.size.y, treeInstancePos.z * terrainData.size.z);
    var worldPos = Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.TransformPoint(localPos);
    resourcePositions.Add(worldPos);
}
```

On the first line we just retrieve the position on the heightmap. Then we convert it to local position and finally to world position.